# How to Automount folder as C: in Dosbox

Tags: dvd, automount, cd-drive, dosbox

I have had a look at the community documentation here and there doesn't seem to be any information about how to "Automount" a folder as the C: drive in Dosbox.

Also as a bonus is it possible to automount the cd/dvd drive in the same way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With DosBox open, type:

`config -writeconf /home/user/dosbox.conf` (or whatever) then exit Dosbox.

Open `dosbox.conf` and add (the `[autoexec]` is at the bottom):

```
[autoexec] 

mount c /home/user/path/to/folder
```

I assume you can do the same for just about any command, it seems to be basically a batch file that is ran at launch.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-auto-mount-a-drive-in-dosbox.html

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been shown how to mount a folder and set it as c drive in `dosbox` (although it is also necessary to add `c:` under the `mount c` line to actually change to that folder), I will address the **second** part of the question and demonstrate a few other `dosbox` commands that can be used to mount optical drives and disk image files.

All the following commands go in the [autoexec] section of your `dosbox.conf`. To select a different conf from the default held in `.dosbox`, generate it with the `config -writeconf` command (as noted in the above answer), edit it and place it in your game folder, and launch the game so that `dosbox` uses the custom conf:

```
dosbox -conf /home/mike/DOS/Game/dosboxgame.conf
```

With regard to your **second** question, you can mount multiple optical drives if you have more than one physical drive connected to your computer. The disc must be mounted in Ubuntu before you start `dosbox`. The `dosbox` command to add to your conf file is, for example:

```
mount d /media/The_Web -t cdrom
```

`Dosbox` also has a very useful feature that allows you to mount a folder *as if it were* a cdrom: this is very useful when the folder contains multiple disk images. A sample command for this that I have in one of my `dosbox` confs is:

```
mount d /home/mike/DOS/EXPRESS/DATA -t cdrom
```

To mount image files that you may have, use the `imgmount` feature, which supports multiple images. I have a command similar to the following example in another of my `dosbox` confs:

```
imgmount d /home/mike/DOS/game/game.iso -t iso
```

or (because `-t iso` or `-t cdrom` both work with disc images) you can use

```
imgmount d /home/mike/DOS/TIMES/Timeshock.cue -t cdrom
```

When you have composed all the entries you need for your conf (and set all the disks and folders to mount), the [autoexec] part of your conf may look this:

```
imgmount d /home/mike/DOS/game/game.iso -t cdrom
mount c /home/mike/DOS/game
c:
game.EXE
```

There is more relevant information in the [dosbox manual](http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html) and on the [useful wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Main_Page).